# Error Propagation vs Standard Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, error

Say you have a set of data of lengths, widths, and heights of a rectangular box. Why do we have to use error propagation to calculate the std. dev. of the box's volume? Why couldn't we calculate the volume associated with each l/w/h datum, and take the std. dev. of that?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you intend by the second sentence? I am not sure I correctly understand what you mean.

Comment: @Glen_b I think they are asking what the benefit of using knowledge of the accuracy of the measuring tools to calculate the error over the behavior of the data to calculate the error is.